# What is the recommended element for a primitive container with minimal style in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I often find a need to nest UI elements (like a button or textblock) inside a box that I can style with a background color, margin, and padding.

There are multiple ways to do this in WPF. Even a Grid works as a simple container. But I want to know what is the recommended go-to element for this purpose? As stated, my most common needs are an element that supports background color, margin, and padding.

Comment: Probably Border, but that's just an opinion. There is nothing like a "recommended" one.

Comment: Questions with `recommendation` very often are off-topic on StackOverflow :/

Comment: Definitely `Border`. In general the answer is "the most simple control you can get away with", which will depend on your specific needs. (There's a fairly good diagram showing most of them [here](http://www.bitcrunch.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/WPF-Class-Hierarchy.png)). The most simple control for something that has content is a ContentControl, but that doesn't implement the background in its template. The next control down in the hierarchy is the UserControl, which is usually used for subclassing, but if you look at it's ControlTemplate it's just a border with a ContentPresenter.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Why don't you put this in an answer so i can accept it? :P

Comment: @Zam This isn't the kind of question that falls under loose opinion or subjective software recommendations. All questions on SO pertain to craft (which is itself based on opinion) and this kind of question is going to have a definite consensus on only a few possible answers. As Mark pointed out, the answer is "the most simple one". My question is an effort to find out which control is the most simple one for this case.

Comment: @Zam done, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely Border. In general the answer is "the most simple control you can get away with", which will depend on your specific needs. (There's a fairly good diagram showing most of them [here](http://www.bitcrunch.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/WPF-Class-Hierarchy.png)). The most simple control for something that has content is a ContentControl, but that doesn't implement the background in its template. The next control down in the hierarchy is the UserControl, which is usually used for subclassing, but if you look at it's ControlTemplate it's just a border with a ContentPresenter:

```
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```